# GDAL SQLite geometry error

Tags: python, ogr, spatialite, sqlite

I am having the following issue writing points to a SQLite file using ogr with SPATIALITE enabed:

> ERROR 1: Cannot insert feature with geometry of type POINTZ in column GEOMETRY. Type POINT expected

Below is my code, this code was previously used to create a GeoPackage with exactly the same fields. (But not with Spatialite enabled because it doesn't have it)

I have commented the code to indicate where the point is created and where the error message comes up

```
import ogr
import numpy as np
import os 
DataSource= ogr.GetDriverByName("SQLite").CreateDataSource(os.path.join(OutputFolder,"DataFile.sqlite"), options = ["SPATIALITE=YES"])
DataLayer = DataSource.CreateLayer("Data_Points",proj,geom_type=ogr.wkbPoint)

DataLayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('ID',ogr.OFTInteger64))
DataLayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('buffer_dist',ogr.OFTInteger64))
DataLayer.CreateField(ogr.FieldDefn('arr_id',ogr.OFTInteger64))

Data_layer_defn = DataLayer.GetLayerDefn()
DataSource.StartTransaction()


data = np.load(os.path.join(OutputFolder,"Output0.npy"))
arr_id = 0
for row in range(len(data)):


    point = ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
    point.AddPoint(float(data[row,1]),float(data[row,2])) #x,y Setting the point

    Data_Feature = ogr.Feature(Data_layer_defn)
    Data_Feature.SetField("ID", int(data[row,0]))
    Data_Feature.SetField("buffer_dist", int(data[row,3]))
    Data_Feature.SetField("arr_id", arr_id)
    Data_Feature.SetGeometry(point)
    DataLayer.CreateFeature(Data_Feature) #Error message happens on this line

    point = None
    arr_id +=1

DataSource.CommitTransaction()
DataSource.FlushCache()
```

Comment: Would you mind to improve you code with required imports etc?

Comment: I have added the imports necessary, there are only two

Comment: I am getting error "NameError: name 'os' is not defined".

Comment: Whoops, I forgot one of the imports "import os", I have edited the post to reflect this.

Comment: 3D geometry seems to be the default. Test with three lines `point=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(float(1.0),float(2.0))
print point.ExportToWkt()
POINT (1 2 0)`. The same appears here https://pastebin.com/ewkKPuVM.

Comment: And so as in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/199820/how-do-i-convert-wkt-geometry-from-3d-to-2d you must flatten 3D into 2D first with `point.FlattedTo2D()`.

Comment: Fantastic this worked perfectly! If you add an answer to this question I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating a point with 2 coordinates actually creates a 3D point as can be tested with

```
point=ogr.Geometry(ogr.wkbPoint)
point.AddPoint(float(1.0),float(2.0))
print point.ExportToWkt()
POINT (1 2 0)
```

You can turn 3D points into 2D points with FlattenTo2D

```
point.FlattenTo2D()
print point.ExportToWkt()
POINT (1 2)
```